# XGBoost get classes WITH labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I"m using XGBoost in python3, I see there are two methods to "get a prediction" `predict()` and  `prob_predict()`.

**First Prize**: Get the top 5 classes with probabilities

**Silver Prize**: Get Top 5 Labels (probabilities)

**Bronze Prize**: How to expose the Labels(Labelencoder ?) and map it to probabilities output from prob_predict

Will the easiest just be to modify sklearn.py and add a function like `predict_n_ext(prediction_count=5)`

Comment: never modify the code source of a library ...